# What would be an alternate to [TearDown] and [SetUp] in MSTest?

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, mstest

When I use MSTest Framework, and copy the code that Selenium IDE generated for me, MSTest doesn't recognize `[TearDown]` and `[SetUp]`. What is the alternative to this?

Comment: Why do we have to always invent some new naming for the same old stuff?

Answer (score 316, accepted):

You would use `[TestCleanup]` and `[TestInitialize]` respectively.

Comment: Setup = [TestInitialize];
TearDown = [TestCleanup]

Answer (score 300):

Keep in mind that your Initialize/Cleanup methods have to use the right signature.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx

```
    [AssemblyInitialize()]
    public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context) {}

    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void ClassInit(TestContext context) {}

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Initialize() {}

    [TestCleanup()]
    public void Cleanup() {}

    [ClassCleanup()]
    public static void ClassCleanup() {}

    [AssemblyCleanup()]
    public static void AssemblyCleanup() {}
```

Comment: +1 for AssemblyInitialize and AssemblyCleanup not mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1873572/864201

Answer (score 108):

`[TestInitialize]` and `[TestCleanup]` at the individual test level, `[ClassInitialize]` and `[ClassCleanup]` at the class level.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `[TestInitialize]` for `[SetUp]` and `[TestCleanup]` for `[TearDown]`.