# Visual Studio 2015 Unit Test HTTP localhost

Tags: unit-testing, localhost, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Creating a stateful API. Because it's using Sessions I cannot use Unit Testing directly to my Controller classes for validation. I need to use HTTP calls.

But when running my Unit Test it doesn't run my project so the HTTP call doesn't find the url http://localhost:54916/api/register

If I run my project and then goto the menu for running Unit Tests it's disabled.

When running my Unit Tests how can I first run the project so that the web/database is online?

Answer (score 0):

Tests that run against real web/database are [integration-tests rather than unit-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357601/whats-the-difference-between-unit-tests-and-integration-tests).

For unit-testing I'd mock the networking\database out of your code in order to test pure logic without relying on the environment that you run on.

For integration-tests, Id create a setup that runs before the tests begin and create the environment that your tests rely on. Of course a teardown that runs after all tests finished their execution that destroys the environment created in setup.
*The setup can be a method special method with dedicated attribute [(MSTest examples)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193744/what-would-be-an-alternate-to-setup-and-teardown-in-mstest) or a build action in your build\CI.