# How can I pass a class or object created to AssemblyInitialize?

Tags: c#, mstest

I want to instantiate an object only once per assembly. How can I pass an object to the AssemblyInit Method?

I'm getting a compilation error. An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property testcounter.

```
namespace Tests
{    
    [TestClass]
    public class Counters
    {   
        int testcounter = 0;
             
        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
        {
           testcounter = 1;
        }
    
        [TestMethod]
        public void testcounter()
        {
           Assert.AreEqual(testcounter,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error is because `testcounter` is not a static field; the error doesn't have anything directly to do with `AssemblyInit`'s parameter.

Comment: i need to initialize some classes which aren't static inside the AssemblyInit. so is this possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible (at least not without trying to circumvent the intended usage of those hooks). Use TestInitialize or ClassInitialize, depending on your specific needs. Mind you that you may prevent (successfull) parallel execution of your tests if you get that wrong. You might consider asking a more specific/detailed question if you need more information. In case of doubt initialize your classes inside each test.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1873191/21567).

Comment: I get the same problem for ClassInitialize. TestInitialize works but it runs every test, which  is what i'm trying to avoid, because initialization for each test takes around 30 seconds to 1 minute.